# Adding AFNetworking to Watchkit

Tags: ios, ios8, watchkit, apple-watch

I have an existing iOS app and I am adding WatchKit support to the app. I installed the AFNetworking library using CocoaPods and now I am trying to include that in the InterfaceController using the line `#import "AFNetworking.h"`

This is giving me the error - `AFNetworking.h file not found`. I tried re-installing the pods, but that did not work.

Comment: first you have add targets to that header with watch kit extension and iPhone and then add this library in "Link with libraries" in watch kit extension

Answer (score 3):

Put this into your **Podfile**

```
link_with 'yourProjectName', 'yourProjectName WatchKit Extension'
```

Answer (score 1):

That's not how to import pods into your project.

Try this:

```
#import <AFNetworking.h>
```